# Error when trying to set dataset to crystal report source

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a physical dataset file in which I did this:

[image]

In the CR designer I set that dataset to a source like this:

[image]

The problem I am facing in the c# code is at this line:

```
document.SetDataSource(rv);
```

Where document is a pre loaded CR document and rv is a dataset which looks like this just before the mentioned line:

[image]

Finally, when I come to that line I get this error. Not even exception is thrown...

[image]

Can anyone help me with this?

This is my code:

```
private void GenerateReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument document = null;
                document = new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();
                document.Load(@"C:\output\CrystalReportTest.rpt");

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("FirstName");
                dt.Columns.Add("LastName");
                dt.Columns.Add("State");
                dt.Columns.Add("Town");
                dt.Columns.Add("ID");

                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "James", "Bond", "England", "London", "1233428749020" });
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Rocky", "Balboa", "USA", "Los Angeles", "471998425060" });
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Keyser", "Soze", "Hungary", "Budapest", "3643428747898" });

                List<DataTable> ldt = new List<DataTable>();
                ldt.Add(dt);


                System.Data.DataSet rv = new System.Data.DataSet();
                rv = AddTableInReportDataSet(ldt);

                if (rv != null)
                {
                    document.SetDataSource(rv);
                }
                document.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, @"C:\output\Export_Test.pdf");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());

            }
        }

        private void SetMainReportDataSource(CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument document, List<DataTable> tables)
        {
            if (tables.Count > 0)
            {
                DataSet reportDataSet = AddTableInReportDataSet(tables);
                document.SetDataSource(reportDataSet);
            }
        }

        private DataSet AddTableInReportDataSet(List<DataTable> tableList)
        {
            DataSet rv = new DataSet();
            tableList.ForEach(tbl => AddTableInReportDataSet(rv, tbl));
            return rv;
        }

        private void AddTableInReportDataSet(DataSet dataSet, DataTable table)
        {
            bool tableAlreadyAdded = dataSet.Tables.Cast<DataTable>().Where(tbl => tbl.TableName == table.TableName).Any();
            if (tableAlreadyAdded)
            {
                foreach (DataRow currentRow in table.Rows)
                {
                    dataSet.Tables[table.TableName].ImportRow(currentRow);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                dataSet.Tables.Add(table);
            }
        }
```

**UPDATE:**

This solved my problem I added this to my app config file:

```
 <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
```

But STILL, my report is empty! Nothing to show!

Comment: What's the inner exception and  the line ?

Comment: I don't know. I can not read anything. @Furtiro

Comment: IoFilesNotFoundException, so i suggest that you double check your document.exportToDisk line and check the path here

Comment: it exists... if I don't try that line, it exports an empty pdf file. @Furtiro

Comment: Please provide all your code, not only a screenshoot, what does that mean 'if i don't try that line ?'

Comment: I added something else, I dont't have error anymore. But also, I don't have data inside. @Furtiro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding name to the table. In the template you use the table named `TestDataTable` but there is no such table in the DataSet (the preview shows it is named `Table1`).